# Sencha Touch 2 datepicker: display another date format for chosen date

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, sencha-touch-2, date-format

I'm using `datepickerfield` in Sencha Touch 2 . It works, the date is selected properly, everything's fine.

The only thing I want is to change the date format: it displays `05/13/2013`, but I want `May 13, 2013`.
Here is my code:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
items: [{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    name: 'mydate',
    picker : {
        yearFrom : parseInt(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y'), 10)-1,
    },
    placeHolder : 'Select Date'
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Adding `dateFormat: 'M d, Y'` was the answer on my question.